# Recurrent Neural Network loss is NAN

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, neural-network

I am training a neural network to use approximately 600 features (4103rd to last column of a df) to predict approximately 4000 values (7th to 4102nd column of the same df). I have standardized the values using standard scaler. I use rmsprop as optimizer and sigmoid as the activation function.

Can someone help me understand how I can improve it?

The code being used is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import statsmodels.api as sm
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

# Extract the features and target values
features = data.iloc[:, -4103:-6].values
targets = data.iloc[:, 6:-5].values

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, targets, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Normalize the data
mean, std = X_train.mean(axis=0), X_train.std(axis=0)
X_train = (X_train - mean) / std
X_test = (X_test - mean) / std

# Define the RNN model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1]))  # Number of target columns
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adagrad')

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train[:, :, np.newaxis], y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10)

# Make predictions
y_pred = model.predict(X_test[:, :, np.newaxis])

# Calculate MSE and R-squared
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)

# Plot predictions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(y_test[:100], label='Actual')
plt.plot(y_pred[:100], label='Predicted')
plt.xlabel('Samples')
plt.ylabel('Target Values')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Print metrics
print("MSE:", mse)
print("R-squared:", r2)
```

Comment: The details matter. In this case, the specific data rows and business use case are going to be central to improving performance. Perhaps LSTM is the appropriate model, and your features are informative and de-noised. Or perhaps not. Absent the specifics, there is little we can say about this. It's not like changing the batch size to 64 is going to   improve your r^2 score by a few percentage points.